# Get geojson for shops only from huge osm file

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson

Is there a way to get filtered geojson data from an huge osm file?

I'm trying to get the geodata for shops only from an **48GB big osm file**. *(full geodata for germany from geofabrik.de)*

I have already converted it into geojson using `mapbox/minjur` but the over **20GB big geojson file is to big for any editor** and cant be included in my TypeScript project to get the wanted data by my own.

If you need further informations let me know as a comment below. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should drop all unwanted data *before* converting it to GeoJOSN.

Use the [tags-filter](https://docs.osmcode.org/osmium/latest/osmium-tags-filter.html) option of [osmium-tool](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/) to extract all shops:

```
osmium tags-filter -R -o shops.osm.pbf germany.osm.pbf shop
```

Then convert to GeoJSON:

```
osmium export shops.osm.pbf -o shops.geojson
```

Comment: Hi there, tanks for your answer. I've installed osmium-tool using `apt-get install osmium-tool` but if i call the first one i get `Unknown command or option 'tags-filter'. Try 'osmium help'.`

Comment: `tags-filter` appreared in version 1.6.0 from 2017-03-07.  Maybe your version is (way) too old? Try to get a newer one, for example at https://github.com/osmcode/osmium-tool.

Comment: You're right. The installed version was 1.5.0, i 've installed v1.10.0 using `apt-get install osmium-tool=1.10.0-1~bpo9+1`. Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot! :)